# use factory design pattern with subclass that has extra constructor arguments

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

suppose i have the following case Parent class, and two Child classes, each child add a new parameter to the parameters inherited from the parent. Example

```
public class Parent {

private int x;

public Parent(int x) {this.x = x;}

public int getX() {return x;}

public void setX(int x) {this.x = x;}
}
```

First child

```
public class FirstChild extends Parent {

private int y;

public FirstChild(int x, int y) {
    super(x);
    this.y = y;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
}
```

Second child

```
public class SecondChild extends Parent{
private int z;

public SecondChild(int x, int z) {
    super(x);
    this.z = z;
}

public int getZ() {
    return z;
}

public void setZ(int z) {
    this.z = z;
}
}
```

so how can i use the factory method here?,

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use "pure" factory or factory method patterns here. These patterns are good when you want to create instances of different subclasses of same base class (or interface) in case that the mechanism of creation the instances is similar. For example all class have constructor or factory method with the same prototype.

In this case you can use reflection or elipsis:

```
class MyFactory {
    Parent createInstance(Class clazz, int ... args) {
        if (FirstChild.class.equals(clazz)) {
            return new FirstChild(args[0]);
        }
        if (SecondChild.class.equals(clazz)) {
            return new SecondChild(args[0], args[1]);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(clazz.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
interface Factory {
    Parent newParent();
} 

class FirstFactory implements Factory {
    Parent newParent() { return new FirstChild(); }
}

class SecondFactory implements Factory {
    Parent newParent() { return new SecondChild(); }
}


class Client {
    public void doSomething() {
        Factory f = ...; // get the factory you need 
        Parent p = f.newParent();
        use(p)
    } 

    // or more appropriately
    public void doSomethingElse(Factory f) {
        Parent p = f.newParent();
        use(p)
    }

}

// Or...

abstract class Client {
    public void doSomething() {
        Factory f = getFactory();
        Parent p = f.newParent();
        use(p)
    } 
    abstract Factory getFactory(); 
}

class FirstClient extends Client {
    Factory getFactory() {
        return new FirstFactory();
    } 
}

class SecondClient extends Client {
    Factory getFactory() {
        return new SecondFactory();
    } 
}
```

Or  (probably fits better what you need) :

```
public class ChildrenFactory {
    FirstChild newFistChild() { return new FirstChild(); } 
    SecondChild newSecondChild() { return new SecondChild(); } 
    // or
    Parent newFistChild() { return new FirstChild(); } 
    Parent newSecondChild() { return new SecondChild(); } 
}
```

Probably you don't really need to use the `Parent` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a factory class which generates either first child or second child as below

```
class Factory{
   Parent createChild(String child) {
      if(child.equals("first"))
         return new FirstChild();
      if(child.equals("second"))
         return new SecondChild();


   }
}
```

Also this link below will help you understand factory pattern better http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/java/factory-design-pattern-in-java